# How to host .net core microservices on IIS server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, microservices

I am a beginner to build microservices in .net core 3.1 and would like to know how to host it on an IIS server with multiple microservices.

I did google but not found any article.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of microservices are just WebApis for a small domain for internal use.

- Typically setup is to use the firewall and/or IP restrictions to avoid access from outside.
- Easiest is to set them up as you would a WebApi with a specific port number for each service.
- As the services call eachother from internally on the server you can use a DNS to translate from service name to ip and port